# github repo created from Rstudio using 'https' but files not uploaded to github

Tags: r, github, version-control, rstudio, git-push

I'm trying to use git from within RStudio to send my project to github. I'm using HTTPS authentication and with this, I can create repository(locally and remotely) and commit changes. However, when i check my github, only repository is created but my `R files`  not found.

This is what i tried

```
library(usethis)
edit_r_environ() 
GITHUB_PAT = 'xxxx...X'  #restart R session
use_github(protocol = 'https', auth_token = Sys.getenv("GITHUB_PAT")) #created a protocol with Access 
token generated from PAT 


#Are title and description ok?
  1: No way
  2: Definitely
  3: Absolutely not

#i typed 2 and entered
```

After the above code, repository was created on github but my R codes are missing. I wanted to use push in git connection but the push/pull was greyed out.
Am aware of other approaches but help using the `usethis` package in R would be apreciated

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://happygitwithr.com/push-pull-github.html

Comment: @phil help but I intent to complete all action from R console